# Why wont my temp table populate data but the select statement inside of it will?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, temp-tables

I have been stuck on a problem that has been a huge blocker for me. I cant seem to wrap my head around this issue and I was hoping someone can help provide me with some guidance.

So my problem is when I create my temp table, and I do

```
select * from all_subs
```

I get a blank table. However, when I test to run the select statement that comprises the temp table I get results...
    My query looks like this

```
drop table if exists all_subs;
select sdb.id as subscription_id,
sdb.created_at,
sdb.user_id as user_id,
sdb.is_gift as is_gift,
case when pl.sku like '%auto-cancel%' then 1 else 0 end as is_auto_cancel,
sdb.current_period_ends_at as current_period_ends_at,
sdb.expires_at as expires_at,
sdb.current_period_started_at as current_period_started_at,
case when sdb.expires_at is null then 0 else 1 end as expiring,
case when pl.sku ilike '%mobi1' then 1
     when pl.sku ilike '%mobi6' then 6
     when pl.sku ilike '%mobi12' then 12
     else pl.duration end as duration,
sdb.dog_name as dog_name,
sdb.dog_birthday as dog_birthday,
pl.sku as sku,
cast(round(100.0 * pl.price, 0) as int) as price,
cast(round(100.0 * pl.price / pl.duration, 0) as int) as mrr,
case
when sdb.expires_at is null and getdate() between sdb.current_period_started_at and sdb.current_period_ends_at  then 'active'
when sdb.expires_at > getdate() then 'canceled'
when sdb.expires_at <= getdate() or (sdb.expires_at is null and sdb.current_period_ends_at < date_add('day',-30,getdate())) then 'expired'
else 'unknown'
end as subscription_state,
coalesce(can.no_new_products, false) as no_new_products,
coalesce(can.dog_did_not_like, false) as dog_did_not_like,
coalesce(can.not_enough_value, false) as not_enough_value,
coalesce(can.dog_died, false) as dog_died,
coalesce(can.cant_afford, false) as cant_afford,
coalesce(can.offer_accepted, false) as offer_accepted,
coalesce(can.too_big_too_small, false) as too_big_too_small,
coalesce(can.allergies, false) as allergies,
coalesce(can.too_much_treats, false) as too_much_treats,
coalesce(can.too_few_toys, false) as too_few_toys,
coalesce(can.toy_durability, false) as toy_durability,
coalesce(can.new_address, false) as new_address,
coalesce(can.something_different, false) as something_different,
case when ais.subscription_id is not null then 1 else 0 end add_item,
case when eets.subscription_id is not null then 1 else 0 end ever_extra_toy,
case when  sdb.allergies = '{""}' then 0
    when sdb.allergies is null then 0
    else 1 end as is_allergy,
min(s.shipped_at) first_box_shipped_at,
count(distinct case when s.shipped_at is not null then o.id end) shipped_orders,
cast((case when (sdb.expires_at <= getdate() or (sdb.expires_at is null and sdb.current_period_ends_at < date_add('day',-30,getdate())))
and count(distinct case when s.shipped_at is not null then o.id end) = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as boolean) is_killed
into temp all_subs
from subscriptions as sdb
left join subscription_cancellation_summary as can on can.subscription_id = sdb.id
left join plans as pl on pl.id = sdb.current_plan_id
left join add_item_subs ais on ais.subscription_id = sdb.id
left join ever_extra_toy_subs eets on eets.subscription_id = sdb.id
left join orders  o on o.orderable_type = 'Subscription' and o.orderable_id = sdb.id
left join orders_shipments os on os.order_id = o.id
left join shipments s on s.id = os.shipment_id
left join common.subs_dim sd on sd.subscription_id = sdb.id
where
-- Only valid subscriptions
sd.is_killed = false
group by sdb.id,
sdb.created_at,
sdb.user_id,
sdb.is_gift,
case when pl.sku like '%auto-cancel%' then 1 else 0 end,
sdb.current_period_ends_at,
sdb.expires_at,
sdb.current_period_started_at,
case when sdb.expires_at is null then 0 else 1 end,
case when pl.sku ilike '%mobi1' then 1
     when pl.sku ilike '%mobi6' then 6
     when pl.sku ilike '%mobi12' then 12
     else pl.duration end,
sdb.dog_name,
sdb.dog_birthday,
pl.sku,
cast(round(100.0 * pl.price, 0) as int),
cast(round(100.0 * pl.price / pl.duration, 0) as int),
case
when sdb.expires_at is null and getdate() between sdb.current_period_started_at and sdb.current_period_ends_at  then 'active'
when sdb.expires_at > getdate() then 'canceled'
when sdb.expires_at <= getdate() or (sdb.expires_at is null and sdb.current_period_ends_at < date_add('day',-30,getdate())) then 'expired'
else 'unknown'
end,
coalesce(can.no_new_products, false),
coalesce(can.dog_did_not_like, false),
coalesce(can.not_enough_value, false),
coalesce(can.dog_died, false),
coalesce(can.cant_afford, false),
coalesce(can.offer_accepted, false),
coalesce(can.too_big_too_small, false),
coalesce(can.allergies, false),
coalesce(can.too_much_treats, false),
coalesce(can.too_few_toys, false),
coalesce(can.toy_durability, false),
coalesce(can.new_address, false),
coalesce(can.something_different, false),
case when ais.subscription_id is not null then 1 else 0 end,
case when eets.subscription_id is not null then 1 else 0 end,
case when  sdb.allergies = '{""}' then 0
    when sdb.allergies is null then 0
    else 1 end;
```

Has anybody come across this issue? Please help!
Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Show the part where you create and populate the temp table.

Comment: i copy and pasted above if you see the top line it says 'drop table if exists all _subs`  and in the middle i have `into temp all_subs`

Comment: Ok. Never seen that sort of table creation notation before. Can you do this instead: `CREATE TEMP TABLE all_subs AS SELECT ...` (rest of your select query there) and see how it works?

Comment: doesn't work. The create temp table runs but I get 0 updated records

Comment: Then try changing the temp table name. I wonder if there's something else with the same name which it's selecting from instead of your temp table. Although if you're saying it's put 0 records in the temp table, then it's not that. What if you create a non-temp table? e.g. `CREATE TABLE t1 AS SELECT ...`

Comment: I've tried changing the name to no avail. might not be a good idea to create tables as this query references other temp tables.

Comment: Yeah I'm just wondering if it can't write to the temp table because it's a temp table, so maybe there's some memory issue, that's why it might be worth writing to a non-temp just to see if that works. But this is just some random speculation. If it still doesn't work with a non-temp table then I don't really have other ideas.

Comment: you and me both... been up all night trying to figure this out. Thank you for your suggestions though

Comment: Note: `WHERE sd.is_killed = false` will degrade the LEFT JOIN to a plain join.

Comment: the `sd.is_killed = false` didnt really affect it, as I mentioned when I run the select statement it populates but not from the temp table

Comment: Do you think it could be a memory issue? This table i am creating has a shit ton of temp tables

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the

```
into temp all_subs
```

to

```
INTO TEMP TABLE all_subs
```

Comment: trying now... looks promising when I just run the query above. I hope it works when I run my whole entire query

Comment: It was written with the postgresql tag in mind (removed now). Need to get myself some test accounts in different environments :)